# Не работает плагин jQuery UI CoverFlow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Хочу поставить на страницу плагин [jQuery UI CoverFlow 2.0](http://addyosmani.com/blog/jqueryuicoverflow/), делаю всё как в демо-примере, но у меня CoverFlow не работает, хотя никаких ошибок в консоли нет.
[Ссылка на мой пример](http://web-portfolio1.narod.ru/test1/index.html) 
В скрипте app.js меняю

```
html: $('#demo-frame div.wrapper').html(),
    imageCaption: $('.demo #imageCaption'),
    sliderCtrl: $('.demo #slider'),
    coverflowCtrl: $('.demo #coverflow'),
    coverflowImages: $('.demo #coverflow').find('img'),
    coverflowItems: $('.demo .coverflowItem'),
    sliderVertical: $(".demo #slider-vertical"),
```

на

```
html: $('div.wrapper').html(),
    imageCaption: $('#imageCaption'),
    sliderCtrl: $('#slider'),
    coverflowCtrl: $('#coverflow'),
    coverflowImages: $('#coverflow').find('img'),
    coverflowItems: $('.coverflowItem'),
    sliderVertical: $("#slider-vertical"),
```

чтобы было как в моей верстке. все остальное как в демо.
ЧЯДНТ?

**UPD** Выяснилось, что ошибка 
*Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'*
вываливается с новыми библиотеками jquery 1.9.1 и jquery-ui 1.10.2,
если подключить старые библиотеки, те же, что были в демо-примере

```
<sсript type="text/javasсript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></sсriрt>
<sсript type="text/javasсript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></sсriрt>
```

то будет работать, но проект будет с новыми версиями библиотек.
Как можно сделать так, чтобы работало и с новыми библиотеками?

Comment: Ошибок в консоли нет? А это что? `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'` 

Chrome 26.0.1410.43 m

Comment: Угу, уже вижу. Как это можно пофиксить?

Comment: судя по тому, что проект убран с github, он мертв

Comment: Переписать/дописать плагин. В исходниках замечены архаизмы, которых нет в новых библиотеках. Их присутствие обязательно скажется на работе плагина.

Comment: @Genson я не настолько хорошо знаю jquery, чтобы переписывать плагин.

Comment: @Heidel и что вы ждете от сообщества ? что мы вам плагин перепишем ? лучше к автору обратитесь, предложите ему денег.

Comment: @eicto перечитайте внимательно мой вопроc. там есть просьба переписать плагин? нет? обратитесь к офтальмологу или психиатру, если вы видите то, чего нет.

Answer (score 1):

[Использование нескольких версий jQuery](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/) ([оф. документация](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)).

Comment: попробую, спасибо.
но уже была попытка подключить новые библиотеки и к ним jquery-migrate - не сработало.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос снимается, потому что, как выяснилось, на github выложена новая версия плагина https://github.com/coverflowjs/coverflow, которая работает с новыми библиотеками jQueryUI 1.9+ и jQuery 1.8+.
А на сайте плагина почему-то лежит старый код(